# Analyzers under Project References shows exclamation sign

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition and loaded the solution, everything worked well but then I observed under every project reference Analyzers were showing up with exclamatory sign.
I was not able to resolve that I tried right clicking onto it and tried performing the Add Analyzer option but it took me to a window with No Items found text in it.
[Please see the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BbKr.jpg)

Note: I installed FxCopAnalyzers for C#, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Can this be an Admin rights thing, pl help!

Comment: You think this can be Windows 10 thing?

Comment: Asked the question in msdn forum too, link below https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f96ee33-db83-44e6-900f-a38e378e0809/analyzers-under-project-references-symbol-doesnt-match-with-other-referenced-dlls?forum=vsdebug